# Rufus V 3 and Kaspersky Bootable USB Flash Drive

Tags: kaspersky, rufus

I was using the latest

1. Rufus - Version 3.11.1678, and
2. Kaspersky - Rescue Disk 2018 - Build 2020.07.05 - Version 18.0.11.0

to create a Bootable Flash Drive.

It has happened twice already that an un-related external USB Hard Drive stopped working!

Initially, I thought something went wrong with the USB Hard Drive but this time, as soon as I permitted Rufus to delete old data on the USB Flash Drive, it killed another un-related External USB Hard Drive on its own.

Rufus had nothing to do with those Hard Drives. It should have not messed with them. I clearly
did not tell Rufus to do anything with those External USB Hard Drives but still they stopped
working! I have yet to recover data from them.

I hope Rufus fixes this problem.

My Computer:

- HP EliteBook 8460P Notebook
- Updated Windows 10, 64-bit
- Updated Kaspersky Anti-virus

Comment: This site is not a bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Rufus developer here.

I'm very surprised to hear your report, as we have actually lots of safety measures in our code to ensure that Rufus simply cannot access the wrong drive, even by mistake. Especially, you are the very first person I know to report that Rufus may be accessing the wrong drive.

For the record, Rufus gets downloaded more than 1 million times each month, and it has a very public [issue tracker](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues) so if Rufus was actually altering data on the wrong drive, we would see plenty of issues about this on the issue tracker.

The fact that we aren't makes me think that, as opposed to what you are assuming, the problem is unlikely to be with Rufus.

For one thing, Rufus produces an extensive log of what it is doing that you can access with the corresponding UI button or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, and without seeing the log of what happened when your hard drives "disappeared", I'm going to assume that the most likely explanation, because your drives are USB is that you selected your hard drive by mistake instead of the flash drive (be mindful that, if you have flaky USB devices or if you plugged a new one, drive selection might have been reset before you press `START`). Especially, 100% of the cases that ever got reported to us of a drive unexpectedly losing data was because the user actually had one device selected in Rufus when they thought they had a different device. By default, Rufus does try not to list USB HDDs to prevent these kind of mishaps, but, because Windows makes it difficult to actually differentiate between a HDD and a regular Flash Drive, we can't guarantee that a USB HDD won't be listed and it's really up to the user to make absolutely sure that the drive selected at the time they press the <kbd>START</kbd> button in Rufus is the correct one.

Now, if this is really a Rufus issue then, after you have recovered your data, you should easily be able to replicate that problem and produce a log to confirm that Rufus is accessing the wrong drive (because, if it already happened to you twice, then it should be easy to replicate one more time). And of course, that log would also tell us if our current assertion, that you may simply have selected the wrong drive by mistake, is correct.

At any rate, without getting a log, and in the absence of anybody else reporting an issue similar to yours, it is just impossible for us to address the problem, if problem there is, as you appear to be the only person in the world able to reproduce it. Especially, even as we are using Rufus on a daily basis (and quite a few other people are too), we have never observed anything like what you report, which of course makes it impossible to identify what, if anything, might requires fixing.

Therefore, if you do manage to replicate this problem, we will invite you to please open an issue in the [official Rufus issue tracker](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues) (which **is** the proper place to report an issue with an Open Source application like Rufus, rather than do it on superuser.com) and make sure you provide your full log so that we can analyse it.